# Identity Columns

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've an identity column which has multiple deletes now it is not working because it reaches the max limit of the  INT data type,
how can I insert records in the place of deleted ones without truncating all the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot "recycle" unused `IDENTITY` values - if you've reached the end of the `INT` data range, you need to change your `ID` column to `BIGINT`.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ALTER COLUMN YourIDColumn BIGINT
```

The `IDENTITY` property will be preserved - now you have a lot of additional ID values available for the next couple months/years to come!

Answer (score 4):

Excuse the obvious...

Did you start at 1, increment of 1? If so, change the identity to -1, -1. It requires a table rebuild but it's easier than changing to bigint. And gives you another 2 billion IDs.

Then plan your bigint migration...

Answer (score 3):

That seems like a lot of work; why not just change the primary key on the table (and any related tables) from an `int` to a `bigint`?

An `int` will give you a max value of 2,147,483,647.

A `bigint` will give you a max value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.